# "Synchronous" useState without useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a list of detected Bluetooth devices, `deviceList`, that is setup with `useState`:

```
const [deviceList, setDeviceList] = useState([]);
```

I have a button that initiates device scans. I need the device list to be reset to `[]` every time a scan starts. I do:

```
const scanForDevices = () =>  {
    setDeviceList([]);

    manager.startDeviceScan(null, null, (error, device) => {
        // add device to device list
        setDeviceList(old => [...old, device]);
    }
}
```

The problem is that `setDeviceList` is not synchronous, and `deviceList` is not reset by the time the new device is supposed to be added. This can result in duplicate devices. I can prevent duplicates by filtering, but that's just a hack on the actual problem.

**I cannot use useEffect to solve this problem so please do not suggest it. `startDeviceScan` cannot be run every time `deviceList` changes.**

How are situations like this solved in the absence of truly atomic `setState`?

Comment: In the implementation you provided it seems that `manager.startDeviceScan` adds only one device at a time. Is this the case?

Comment: @fgkolf That is correct

Comment: So if `setState` was atomic somehow as you said, you would always end up with an array of one device, since `old` would be an empty array.

Comment: Then what is the right solution?

Comment: Ignore the old state and `setDeviceList([device]);` but i am not sure this is what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to clear the list and `startDeviceScan` is returning multiple devices, it seems like you could create a temporary variable to build the list and then set the state when you're finished.

```
const scanForDevices = () =>  {
    const devices = [];

    manager.startDeviceScan(null, null, (error, device) => {
        // add device to device list
        devices.push(device);
    }

    setDeviceList(devices);
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but `startDeviceScan` doesn't finish until user action.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `useReducer` hook to change your state? I haven't tried to solve a timing issue like yours with this hook, but it's worth a shot.

The solution might look something like this (untested):

```
const initialState = []
const reducer = (state, {type, payload}) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'RESET':
      return initialState
    case 'ADD_DEVICE':
      return [...state, payload]
    default:
      return state
  }
}
const [deviceList, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)

...

const scanForDevices = () =>  {
  dispatch({type: 'RESET'})

  manager.startDeviceScan(null, null, (error, device) => {
    // add device to device list
    dispatch({type: 'ADD_DEVICE', payload: device})
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately my understanding is that `useReducer` is also not synchronous, and that in fact `useState` uses `useReducer` under the hood.

Comment: @T3db0t Yep, also asynchronous. I was just thinking it might make the updates sequentially, the way that Redux does with its reducers.